# Referencing a file from application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-data-jpa

My config in the application.properties file is

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:1234/db_name?ssl=true&sslmode=require&sslrootcert=ca.crt&sslkey=client.some_cert.key8&sslcert=client.some_cert.crt`

The files are in the resources folder for a maven based spring boot application but I keep getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

What's the best way of referencing these files?

Answer (score 0):

If the Java dont have the Class to read the variable like ConfigurationManager on C#, you can read the file and search by the tag and take the value after =

Answer (score 0):

When a parameter is missing it does not return this exception it returns the missing attribute, post the complete exception.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please post this as a comment, as it does not answer the question.